# How to setup a configuration file for Pylint in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, batch-file, ide, spyder, pylint

How do I specify a custom configuration file for Pylint (command line switch `--rcfile`) in Spyder IDE?

I tried editing `pylint.bat` and `pylint-gui.bat` like this:

```
python "%~dpn0" %* --rcfile="P:/path/to/pylintrc"
```

but without success. I always see in the output:

> No config file found, using default configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spyder will run pylint.exe, not pylint.bat, that's why what you tried doesn't work.

The easiest way is to put your pylintrc in your project folder, as pylint will automatically look there.

https://docs.pylint.org/run.html#command-line-options

EDIT: The link above seems to have died. See here: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options